# Error while trying to add developer in Facebook Developer Console

Tags: facebook, android-facebook

I am trying to add a developer in facebook developer console.

When I submit the developer E-mail_Id, it gives me an error, `"param must be non-empty"`

I have added the message window for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the error message is not very informative.

Resolved this issue. Something amiss with the configuration. I created a fresh Facebook project and 
configured app_id in Android manifest file once again. Further,

1. Ensure that configurations in Facebook developer console are correct.
2. Ensure that developer is friend of the Facebook Admin.
3. When you start typing names in the box it should automatically populate the name.
4. Add the person.

Pending status will go automatically in sometime.